# Can't Connect Mongodb to Springboot Container in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have tried many options to access the MongoDB image from docker. It works fine outside the docker but If I run the application in docker container it shows me an error. Mentioned below are screenshots of errors. Also, shared the code of connection and commands which I am running.

Exception while running spring boot application

[image: logs]

Mongo Db Container Running
[image: containers]

Java Code used for connecting docker MongoDB image

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb//db", 27017));
```

I tried with alternative options also

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017));
```

It works fine if I run the jar directly but doesn't work inside the docker container.

Kindly provide me the solution.

Comment: How you're starting the containers? With a compose file or with `docker run`?

Comment: The problem is that, you're accessing the DB with wrong IP/hostname. Post your compose file or run commands so that I can pin point the issue. @PriyankaKanse

Comment: @SaqibAhmed I run through docker run.

Comment: @SaqibAhmed docker file FROM java:8

VOLUME /tmp

ADD block-V1.0.jar ////app.jar

RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'

EXPOSE 9081

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]

Comment: Post your docker run commands to start DB and spring application

Comment: @SaqibAhmed for mongo docker run -d -P --name db mongo For Springboot docker run -d  block. Even I tried this also docker run -d -P  --link db:db block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169836/discussion-between-saqib-ahmed-and-priyanka-kanse).

Comment: @SaqibAhmed I am facing this error exception opening socket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Problem

You're trying to access the DB with wrong IP/hostname. As you can see, accessing `localhost` in the spring container would resolve to that container and there's no `27017` port listening there. When you run the jar on docker host, it has `27017` port available, that's why it works.
[image]

### Solution

You can use `--hostname` flag in `docker run` command to set the hostname of DB container so that you can connect to it from the Spring container using the hostname.

The better solution, however, is to use a docker-compose file and start the containers using `docker-compose up`.

First of all use

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("db", 27017));
```

in your Spring code and build an image of your code.

Afterward, follow the steps below to start the containers:

### A) Create Compose file

Create a file named `docker-compose.yml` with following content:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  app:
    # replace imageName with your image name (block in your case)
    image: imageName:tag
    ports:
      - 9876:4000 # Replace the port of your application here if used
    depends_on: 
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

### B) Run the compose file

Execute following command to run the compose file:
`docker-compose up -d`