# Spring-boot application in docker container is unable to connect to mongodb docker container

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

When I trying to run my spring-boot application on docker , it is not able to connect to the Mongodb container running in docker.

Application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

Dockerfile for spring application

```
FROM openjdk
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: docker-mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  wacaj_docker:
    image: wacaj
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    container_name: wacaj
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

I am able to connect to the mongodb container from my local system , but the spring-application container is not able to connect to mongo container.
And also if I run the spring application in local it is able to connect to the mongo runneing in docker container.
I am unable to troubleshoot the problem.

I tried changing hostname to both servicename i.e. mongo
and container name i.e. docker-mongo, but it is still not working.

```
2023-01-07 08:50:03.146  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
wacaj         | 
wacaj         | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
wacaj         |         at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
wacaj         |         at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
wacaj         |         at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
wacaj         |         at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
wacaj         |         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
wacaj         | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
wacaj         |         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
wacaj         |         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
wacaj         |         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:539) ~[na:na]
wacaj         |         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:594) ~[na:na]
wacaj         |         at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
wacaj         |         at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
wacaj         |         at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
wacaj         |         at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
wacaj         |         at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
```

Comment: what error it gives you? you have not specified network in your docker file, the default network is bridge I believe, you are trying to access the port on the host, so I think you should set the network to host

Comment: or change spring.data.mongodb.host to point to the mongo db container through docker network, so spring.data.mongodb.host=docker-mongo

Comment: Yes, i am using the default network.

Comment: 2023-01-07 08:50:03.146  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
wacaj         | 
wacaj         | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
wacaj         |         at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]

Comment: @Pavel A Compose file with no `networks:` blocks is a good setup: Compose creates a network named `default` and all of the normal container networking features work fine.  You should _not_ need host networking for this case.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: This question seems very similar to [SpringBoot in Docker not connecting to Mongo in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938511/springboot-in-docker-not-connecting-to-mongo-in-docker), though it seems somewhat inconclusive.  Definitely `localhost` ("the current container") is wrong and `spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo` is right (maybe set in an environment variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the hostname:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo
```

Docker makes every service in a docker compose setup available under its service name, in your case `mongo` and `wacaj_docker`.

Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for further details.

Comment: I tried this but it is still not working .. I have added the error message in the question post. Thanks for reply.

Comment: In your error message it says `connecting to server localhost:27017`. What is the error message when you use `spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo`?

Comment: The problem was that when I was using docker compose up , it was not updating the old image.

Comment: I deleted the image and ran docker compose up after changing the host name and it worked. Thansk